# Git Hub GitIgnore error

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I keep getting this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    .gitignore
```

How do I make it ignore the .gitignore file in my HOME directory?

My .gitignore looks like this and is being ignored:

```
# Can also ignore all directories and files in a directory.
app/config/**
app/config/**/*
plugins/**
vendors/shells/**/*
```

Comment: Maybe because you pose the wrong question (the solution isn't to ignore the .gitignore file). That's a little harsh but don't worry too much for one downvote. BTW, if you use a gui for git operations, or have a reason to think the .gitignore file has been made automatically, precise it.

Comment: What do you mean " my HOME directory" ? The .gitignore file(s) must be in the git repository. Are you putting your linux home under git ?

Comment: just found a website that said put it in your home, so instead put it in HOME/.git/.gitignore then?

Comment: Say you have a project in `~myuser/myproject/` the best place to put your global `.gitignore` file is `~myuser/myproject/.gitignore`. Don't put anything in the `.git` directory.

Comment: yeah in git terms HOME = myproject where the file is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ignore it.

But commit it. There is no reason not to save this file.

If you commit it and then merge, the merge will (probably correctly) add your rules and the received ones.

Comment: okay then i did git add . and then git commit -m "test" but now gitignore isn't working at all

Comment: added it above but its being ignored

Comment: then i did cat .gitignore and that what came up, but my app/config files are still showing an error

Comment: If you did commit those files before (with a `-a` for example) you need to remove them manually from index.